# Does C# 6 Elvis operator (null propagation) short circuit

Tags: c#-6.0

Why this c# code throws a null exception?

```
bool boolResult = SomeClass?.NullableProperty.ItsOkProperty ?? false;
```

Isn´t elvis operator supposed to stop evaluation (short circuit) once the NullableProperty evaluates to null?

In my understanding the line of code above is a shortcut for:

```
bool boolResult 
if(SomeClass != null)
    if(SomeClass.NullableProperty != null)
        boolResult = SomeClass.NullableProperty.ItsOkProperty;
    else
        boolResult = false;
else
    boolResult = false;
```

Did I assume wrong?

EDIT: Now I understand why I get it wrong, The line of code actually translates to something similar to:

```
bool boolResult 
if(SomeClass != null)
    boolResult = SomeClass.NullableProperty.ItsOkProperty;
else
    boolResult = false;
```

And throws because NullableProperty is null...

Comment: Ah, I think what you wanted was `SomeClass?.NullableProperty?.ItsOkProperty`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to chain, since the NRE is on the second reference:

```
bool boolResult = SomeClass?.NullableProperty?.ItsOkProperty ?? false;
```

Comment: does the result need to be nullable? i.e. bool?

Comment: The ?? operator at the end performs conversion to false if the result of the left-hand operator is null, therefore the result will always be true or false.